# estimate how much time to migrate to wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure

I have a web app that I'm building. It uses 3 different web services in ASMX format and altogether, these web services hold a total of 8 different web methods. The code behind of each web service is very short (about 5 lines per web method) and essentially just instantiates a class and passes it the parameter received. Each web service makes use of session state and they currently run in HTTP mode. The app itself runs in IIS.

I'd like to migrate my app to AZURE, migrate the ASMX web services to WCF and make the whole app work with HTTPS.

Which should I do first: a) port the app to azure; b) convert from ASMX to WCF; c) convert logged-in pages from HTTP to HTTPS?

How much time could it roughly take to do part b) given the way they're built ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out The challenge of migration – determining Windows #Azure migration complexity http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidmcg/archive/2011/09/22/the-challenge-of-migration-determining-windows-azure-migration-complexity.aspx and also a sample Migrating the .Net Pet Shop to Windows #Azure: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidmcg/archive/2011/10/05/migrating-the-net-pet-shop-to-windows-azure.aspx

Personally I would do B, C and then A

hth

Cheers

Comment: Agreed.  Hardest migration will be to WCF, so I'd start there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do them in any order that you like.  I think C, B, A but any order should be fine.

It shouldn't take long to convert to WCF, it is pretty similar in nature.